# How to label a figure and call it using the command \vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=...em]{C:/Users/abc/Documents/...}}}?

Tags: captions, includegraphics

I am unable to give the figure a name or figure number using the following latex command for, instance:
`$\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=6.6em]{C:/Users/abc/Documents/g2}}}$`. Thanks

Comment: Can you please make a complete minimal example? What's the reason for `\vcenter`? Are you using a `figure` environment?

Comment: @egreg $\vcenter$ is used just to center the argument and g2 is my figure's file name in my computer saved in C drive.

Comment: That's clear. What's needed is to know *where and how* you use those commands. Please, add some context.

Comment: @David Carlisle sorry i am not familiar in drawing figures in normal latex constructs.

Comment: @egreg  I am using a software to draw figures and save into my computer and  using the above latex commands,  i am able to include my figures in latex file which runs successfully, but i couldn't name the figure and call it in the text to refer

Comment: \caption is picky.  If \@captype isn;t set. it won't run.  It also doesn't like \hbox, and is not too fond of \parbox.  I would use \captionof and minipage.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[height=6.6em]{example-image}
  \caption{An example image\label{eximg}}
\end{figure}

Some text, see Figure \ref{eximg}.

\end{document}
```